# Como os ícones de um programa não precisam estar numa pasta de recursos ou algo do tipo?

Tags: resources, .exe, ícone

Estou usando Java, mas é uma pergunta bem geral, na verdade.

Quando carrego uma imagem como ícone de um programa (ícone do programa, de salvar, carregar, qualquer ícone) e mudo a pasta onde o ícone está, naturalmente acontece um erro pelo fato de o programa procurar o ícone em um endereço desatualizado.

Como solução, criei uma pasta de recursos na mesma pasta do projeto do programa, para armazenar os ícones que estou utilizando.

Por quê programas (como Word, Adobe File Reader, Solidworks ou AutoCAD, etc.) geralmente não tem, pelo menos aparentemente, uma pasta com os ícones utilizados no programa? Como isso acontece?

Comment: Nada impede de os recursos estarem dentro do próprio executável. Tem várias formas de se fazer isso, que dependem do OS, compilador, linguagem etc.

Comment: Você poderia me dar um exemplo? Ou uma direção pra seguir pesquisando isso?
Acho que isso pode facilitar minha vida pra carregar os ícones e imagens do meu programa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um executável padrão pode ter *recursos* dentro dele além do código binário de execução. Como já deve saber isso é chamado de [*resources*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_(Windows)) (nome no Windows, mas pode fazer no [Linux também](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967), e no MacOS usa-se [*bundles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(OS_X))).

Pode ser textos ou outros formatos de dados diversos, inclusive imagens de diversos formatos como os ícones.

Existem alguns utilitários para ver o que tem dentro dele ou manipular esses dados ([Exemplo](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), [Exemplo](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html), [Exemplo](http://www.resedit.net/)). Obviamente um *linker* permite fazer essa manutenção na sua forma mais básica ([documentação do *linker* da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160)). Os IDEs costumam ter alguma coisa que ajuda nisso. Tem como [fazer programaticamente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-updateresourcea?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Em tese poderia fazer isso em Java, mas ele já tem que juntar outras coisas, não faz tanta diferença ter algo assim. O que poderia fazer é um mecanismo próprio criando um *array* de *bytes* e jogar os *bytes* do ícone nele. Não tem muito segredo. Aí pega esse *array* e faz o que desejar como se tivesse lido de um arquivo.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você disse, mas consegui perceber que a resposta tá BEM completa. Gostei dessa última ideia do array de bytes, vou tentar estudar pra fazer isso. Obrigado pelos links também, vão ajudar muito. Obrigado bigown! =D